# Unscented Kalman Filter - Bayes++

Tags: ros, filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

Does anybody have any experience how to include UKF from [Bayes++](http://bayesclasses.sourceforge.net/Bayes++.html) into ROS.
I can't get it to build.

I'm constantly getting errors like:

```
...Bayes++/BayesFilter/bayesFlt.hpp:588: undefined reference to `VTT for Bayesian_filter::Unscented_scheme'
```

Any tips are welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35319/unscented-kalman-filter---bayes++/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made a port of Bayes++ to ROS, it's not finished but you could give it a try.

https://github.com/miquelmassot/bayes_filter_ros

what I did in order to build it was to create a ROS package and, in the CMakelists add

> //Set the dependencies of Bayes++

> rosbuild_add_boost_directories()

> SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-msse3")

> //Source the files from Bayes++ and compile the library

> rosbuild_add_library(BayesFilter external_libs/include/BayesFilter/bayesFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/bayesFltAlg.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/CIFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/covFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/infFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/infRtFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/itrFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/matSup.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/SIRFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/UDFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/UdU.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/unsFlt.cpp
> external_libs/include/BayesFilter/bayesFlt.cpp)

it builds a "libBayesFilter.so" that you can later use.

---

Originally posted by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) with karma: 1471 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-06-01**:
Great work. Thank you. I finally built my project.